# Trouble with python connect 4 column full

Tags: python, python-3.x, connect-four

I'm making a connect 4 game on python but I'm running into an issue with my play function

```
def play(grid,column,checker):
    
    counter = 0
    for x in grid[0]:
        counter += 1
    if counter > column-1 :
        for row in reversed(grid):
            while row[column-1] == "empty":
                row[column-1] = checker
                print(True)
                return True
            else :
                return False 
            
            

    else:
        print(False)
        return False
```

I'm trying to figure out how to make it return false if the column is full but I can't seem to get it to work. Grid is a list of lists provided from a previous function. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `return` stops the function, I don't think you can directly want to use it in your while/else

Comment: I tried using print but it printed false out multiple times even when the column wasn't full.

Comment: Try printing the values of counter and column before the if statement. Print the value of row[column-1] before the while statement. See if they match what you expected.

Comment: Maybe print your grid too. You should know what values are in all the variables when troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want else return False. You want to return false if the for loop fails to find a an open slot

Try this:

Edit: I changed code to be a solution I tested

```
def play(grid, column, checker):
    try:    
        counter = 0
        for x in grid[0]:
            counter += 1
        if counter > column-1 :
            for row in reversed(grid):
                if row[column-1] == "empty":
                    row[column-1] = checker
                    return True

            return False
        else:
            return False  
    finally:
        print(grid)

grid = [['empty']*7 for _ in range(7)]
column = 3
assert play(grid, column, 'O') == True
assert play(grid, column, 'X') == True
assert play(grid, column, 'O') == True
assert play(grid, column, 'X') == True
assert play(grid, column, 'O') == True
assert play(grid, column, 'X') == True
assert play(grid, column, 'O') == True
assert play(grid, column, 'X') == False
```

Disclaimer: I did this with minimal changes and only to resolve the return False problem. I did not try to validate other logic. Also, you should change the while to an if statement as you aren't looping.

Comment: Thanks for the advice on the while loop! I did try this out before asking the question and unfortunately did not get the results that I am looking for however I really appreciate the thought and thank you for contributing.

Comment: Over time, you will use the return False if something didn't happen in the loop pattern a lot and it will become automatic. I don't see many people use while..else. You might want to be careful with that as it might not be working the way you expect it to.

Comment: I switched it over to a for loop instead but I still cant figure out the problem.

Comment: I'll make an edit with code that is working for me and that is close to your code